Converting project from JS to TS results in build failure
This is my project tree
buildDataGridMessages.ts
import fs from 'fs-extra';
import prettier from 'prettier';

import path from 'path';

import json from '../src/DataGrid/locale/json';

const rootDir = path.join(__dirname, '..');

const createMessages = () => {does something}

package.json
{
  "name": "@ayx/onyx-ui-lab",
  "version": "8.0.0-2.1.0",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "module": "index.es.js",
  "sideEffects": [
    "*.css"
  ],
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm-run-all clean build:data-grid-messages build:icons build:extensionIcons build:typescript build:es2015 build:es2015modules build:copy-files",
    "build:copy-files": "npm-run-all  build:copy-package-json build:copy-ts-defs",
    "build:copy-package-json": "copyfiles -f \"../lab/package.json\" build",
    "build:copy-ts-defs": "copyfiles -u 1 \"./src/**/*.d.ts\" build",
    "build:data-grid-messages": "node ./scripts/buildDataGridMessages",
    "build:es2015": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src -x \".ts\" -x \".tsx\" -x \".js\" --out-dir ./build",
    "build:es2015modules": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production BABEL_ENV=modules babel ./src/index.ts --out-file ./build/index.es.js",
    "build:extensionIcons": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel ./src/ExtensionIcons/icons --out-dir ./build/ExtensionIcons/icons --ignore *.test.js",
    "build:icons": "node ./scripts/buildExtensionIcons",
    "build:typescript": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json",
...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.4",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@babel/cli": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^15.0.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-remove-properties": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-dev-warning": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "base64-img": "^1.0.4",
    ...
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "normalize-path": "^3.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.5",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-intl": "^6.6.5",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17 || ^18",
    "react-dom": "^17 || ^18"
  }
}


tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build"
  },
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ],
  "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom"],
}

tsconfig.build.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": [
    "src/**/*.test.tsx",
    "./setupTests.ts",
    "./setupUserEvents.ts",
    "src/**/**/initializeUnitTest.tsx"
  ]
}


Executing npm run build fails at build:data-grid-messages with the message Error: Cannot find module '/Users/nainshi.nayan/Documents/workspace/onyx-ui/packages/lab/scripts/buildDataGridMessages'
These are the options I tried:

installed ts-node and updated the buildDataGridMessages path in the script to "build:data-grid-messages": "ts-node ./scripts/buildDataGridMessages.ts". It failed with this error

(node:95565) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/nainshi.nayan/Documents/workspace/onyx-ui/packages/lab/scripts/buildDataGridMessages.ts:1
import fs from 'fs-extra';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module


I added "type": "module" in package.json and updated the file name in the script to "build:data-grid-messages": "ts-node ./scripts/buildDataGridMessages". It failed with

TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for /Users/nainshi.nayan/Documents/workspace/onyx-ui/packages/lab/scripts/buildDataGridMessages.ts


Removed "type": "module" from package.json and updated "module": "es2015", and "target": "es2015" to the compilerOptions in tsconfig.json. It failed with this error

(node:96144) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/Users/nainshi.nayan/Documents/workspace/onyx-ui/packages/lab/scripts/buildDataGridMessages.ts:10
import fs from 'fs-extra';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
^^^^^^

babel.config.js
const ENV = process.env.BABEL_ENV;
module.exports = {
  assumptions: {
    setPublicClassFields: true,
  },
  env: {
    development: {
      plugins: [
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              modules: './modules',
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    es: {
      // It's most likely a babel bug.
      // We are using this ignore option in the CLI command but that has no effect.
      ignore: ['**/*.test.js', '**/*.test.tsx', '**/testData.js'],

      plugins: [
        'transform-react-constant-elements',
        'transform-dev-warning',
        ['react-remove-properties', { properties: ['data-mui-test'] }],
        [
          'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
          {
            mode: 'wrap',
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    production: {
      // It's most likely a babel bug.
      // We are using this ignore option in the CLI command but that has no effect.
      ignore: ['**/*.test.js', '**/*.test.tsx', '**/testData.js'],

      plugins: [
        'transform-react-constant-elements',
        'transform-dev-warning',
        ['react-remove-properties', { properties: ['data-mui-test'] }],
        [
          'transform-react-remove-prop-types',
          {
            mode: 'wrap',
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
    test: {
      presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]],
    },
  },
  ignore: ['scripts/*.js', '**/*.d.ts', '**/initializeUnitTest.tsx', '**/DataGrid/locale/json'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-imports',
      {
        '@ayx/icons/?(((\\w*)?/?)*)': {
          transform: importName => {
            const splitName = importName.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
            const folderName =
              splitName !== null ? splitName.join('-').toLocaleLowerCase() : importName.toLocaleLowerCase();
            if (importName.includes('Svg')) {
              return `@ayx/icons/svg/${folderName}`;
            }
            return `@ayx/icons/icons/${folderName}`;
          },
        },
        '@ayx/onyx-ui': {
          transform: importName => {
            let path;
            if (styles.includes(importName)) {
              path = `@mui/styles/${importName}`;
            } else if (coreStyles.includes(importName)) {
              path = `@mui/material/styles/${importName}`;
            } else if (transitions.includes(importName)) {
              path = `@mui/material/transitions/${importName}`;
            } else {
              path = importName === 'dataUICMaker' ? `@ayx/onyx-ui/utils` : `@ayx/onyx-ui/${importName}`;
            }
            return path;
          },
        },
        '@ayx/onyx-ui-common': {
          transform: '@ayx/onyx-ui-common/${member}',
        },
        '@mui/lab': {
          preventFullImport: true,
          transform: '@mui/lab/${member}',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
  ],
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        modules: ['modules', 'production-umd'].includes(ENV) ? false : 'commonjs',
        targets: {
          browsers: [
            '>0.2%',
            'not dead',
            'not op_mini all',
            'last 2 chrome version',
            'last 2 firefox version',
            'last 2 safari version',
            'last 2 edge version',
          ],
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
};

